# Windows Defender Real Time Scan

Tags: malware, windows-defender

Windows Defender would not detect in real time a new Malware hidden in a .zip file.
If I scan the .zip file after it was downloaded from the website it does detect it and deletes it.

Zip file is not protected and it has a simple .exe inside; there are no exemptions an no other specific rules.

Any ideas on where to look and what could be wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but to close it as off-topic seems wrong to me. Why would it be off-topic @sven?

Comment: This is for Windows Defender managed by SCCM in a Business Environment @sven so I believe it should be on topic.

Comment: @Lenniey The issue is that  users can download some Malware ( specifically 1 .zip file ) and Windows Defender does not detect it in Real Time but it does if the file is scanned either manually after it was downloaded or by the scheduled Scan.

Comment: But on the same PC using the same definitions in an active scan it is detected? Is real-time scanning even enabled?

Comment: @Lenniey yes, in an active scan with the same definitions it is detected. Real Time scanning is enabled; it does puzzles me as well on why this behavior. It does detect other Malware files in Real Time.

Comment: Any configured path/file/extension-exceptions?

Comment: No path or file or extension exceptions. If I text with the Eicar Zip Malware files it works.

Comment: What's the output of `Get-MpPreference | fl *Archive*`? Do you have the GPO "Scan archive files" disabled?